# 2 questions on 4-velocity

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

Firstly 4-velocity is defined by $u^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ let us consider the component $x_i$ of $x^\mu$ then this derivative can be written as:
$$\frac{dx_i}{d\tau}=\frac{dx_i}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau}$$ where since $t=\tau \gamma$ then $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\gamma$ But why is this so? does $\gamma$ not change with time and therefore depend on $\tau$ especially in the case where the body is accelerating?

Secondly for a if in a given frame we have $x_{CM}^\mu =m_1x^{\mu}_1+m_2x^{\mu}_2$ for the centre of mass of two particles 1 and 2 does this then imply that (for the ith component):
$$\gamma_{u_{CM}}(m_1 \dot x_1+m_2 \dot x_2)=\gamma_{u_1}m_1\dot x_1 +\gamma_{u_2}m_2\dot x_2$$ depending if you use the chain rule first then split the terms up or split $x^\mu$ up and then use the chain rule. If one is wrong can you explain which one thanks.

Comment: In special relativity, $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ which is a constant, since we only consider inertial frames (which have constant $v$). In general relativity, $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ is no longer equal to $\gamma$, but is more complicated and in general is not constant.

Comment: @Prahar but many textbooks I have seen go onto derive a formula for 4-acceleration using this 4-velocity. But in this case $\gamma$ cannot be constant else the acceleration would always be 0?!

Comment: Yes, but you have to be careful which $\gamma$ they are using. In special relativity, one talks about inertial frames and objects. Inertial frames have a constant velocity $v$ implying that their $\gamma$ is constant. Objects can have any $v$ and for them the $\gamma$ is not constant.

Comment: I presume you derived $t = \tau \gamma$ as the time-dilation formula. That formula relates the time measured in two frames and is therefore valid only for constant $v$.

Comment: @Prahar Ok so I get you point with $t=\tau \gamma$ which simply means that I canot use this formula to find $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$, so what formula can I use, if we are allowing the particle to accelerate and still get the same 4-velocity equation?

Comment: The correct formula is $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma$. It is most easily derived from the metric $c^2 d\tau^2 = c^2 dt^2 - d\vec{x}^2 = ( c^2 - v^2 ) dt^2$. This gives you the formula that you are looking for.

Comment: @Prahar let us say we have the four position $x^\mu=(ct,x_1+x_2,0,0)$ In this case does $v$ Have to be $(\dot x_1+\dot x_2)$ which will mean that the answer to the second part of my question is that the first equation is right and the second wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18942/discussion-between-prahar-and-joseph).

Comment: I saw in the Internet this article: http://www.normalesup.org/~baglio/physique/acceleration.pdf . Could it help?